# Error al usar Ajax AutoComplete for jQuery devbridge

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy usando jquery autocomplete devbridge, estoy implementando con una llamada ajax desde angularjs el cual me trae un Json de la siguiente manera:

```
var arrayListAuto =[
   "Mio",
   "Tio",
   "Otro"
 ]
```

y lo llamo asi con el plugin de Autocompletar

```
$("#autocomplete-linea-principal").autocomplete({
                lookup: arrayListAuto
            });
```

pero cuando debe mostrar la lista de sugerencias me sale el siguiente error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Comment: Hola, estas seguro que el error proviene de esta parte del código? no parece haber ningún problema aquí.

Comment: A mi parecer creo que no tiene un valor para evaluar, y cuando lo corres aparece esto.

Answer (score 0):

El autocomplete espera un parámetro con el formato

```
var arrayListAuto = [
   { value: 'Mio', data: 'Mio' },
   { value: 'Tio', data: 'Tio' },
   { value: 'Otro', data: 'Otro' }
];
```